# Can loopback.io operation hooks be registered only once per model?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying out operation hooks http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks

Here is what I did in app code:

```
    mymodel.observe('before save', doSomething);

    //after some time elapses or based on an event we want to change the behaviour
    mymodel.observe('before save', doSomethingElse);


    var doSomething = function (ctx, next) {
        //do something
        next();
    };

    var doSomethingElse = function (ctx, next) {
        //do something else
        next();
    };
```

When I test this code I find that always doSomething is executed which makes me wonder if the observer function can be registered only once per model or is it a bug?

If it is as per design, could you please tell the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am a core developer of LoopBack and the author of Operation hooks.*

> after some time elapses or based on an event we want to change the behaviour

The Operation hooks do not support unregistering of handler functions yet. Each call of `observe()` adds the handler to the list of methods invoked when a hook is triggered.

> When I test this code I find that always doSomething is executed which makes me wonder if the observer function can be registered only once per model or is it a bug?

You can register multiple observers. Once you have registered `doSomething`, it will be always called. When you register `doSomethingElse`, it will be called too, after `doSomething` returns via `next()`.

Comment: is it guaranteed that multiple registered handlers get called in the same order they where added (like in the above code among each other) ?

Comment: The current implementations works that way. We may decide to change this behaviour if there are good reasons/needs in the future, but such change would have to be released in a new major version.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš We have a use-case for removing operation hooks at runtime (in testing) - what is the best way to report that and ask for an enhancement?

Comment: I have exactly the same use case (using an EventSource example from https://gist.github.com/njcaruso/ffa81dfbe491fcb8f176).

Comment: Since the last time I commented, we have implemented support for removing both a single observer (MyModel.removeObserver) and all observers at once (MyModel.clearObservers). See http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#observermixin

Answer (score 1):

You can now unregister all observers with the `clearObservers` method and remove a single observer with the `removeObserver` method. See the [ObserverMixin documentation.](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#observermixin)

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/master/CHANGES.md), this feature was added in version 2.23.0 of the datasource juggler.